# react split string into words and letters, including spaces with the addition of a ref for each letter

Tags: reactjs

I have a string like "Hello world!".

At the finish I want to see like this: H e l l o       w o r l d !

And **ref** element for every letter 1 2 3 4 5    6 7 8 9 10 11

```
   {"Hello world!".split(" ").map((word, index) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="
            mr-4
            flex
          ">
          {word.split("").map((letter, i) => {
            return (
              <div
                className="inline-block"
                key={i}
                ref={(el) => {
                  itemsRef.current[i] = el;
                }}>
                {letter}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>            
      );
    })}
```

Everything is working now, but the ref for letters looks like this: 1 2 3 4 5    1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: at the very top you're splitting the string using the spacebar as delimiter, which gives you two elements: `["Hello", "world!"]`. remove that, and you'll be able to map by letter.

Comment: But at the enter I have a string with many words (example: "hello world!", "lorem pixel set amet")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to calculate the index based on the parent loop index and current word length

`itemsRef.current[index * word.length + i] = el;`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sh3oan?file=App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is for each word you start calculation of index from the beginning: in your case **"Hello world!".split(" ")** this gives you 2, and you are starting twice from the beginning: **word.split("")**

The simplest solution what can I recommend you is to use length of the list as an index for the next element.

```
itemsRef.current[itemsRef.current.length] = el
```